# Logistic Regression: What do people exactly mean by "cell size"? (example: small cell N's but no warning messages and convergence criteria met.)

Tags: statistics, sas, sample, logistic-regression

I've been performing some logistic regressions and found some great results.  The problem is I'm unsure if my model is stable or not.  This is mostly because I am confused about what people mean by cell size for logistic regression.

I keep reading inconsistent prescriptions. Some people say I need 10-15 observations per variable while some people say I need 10-15 observations per cell.  I also get confused if people mean per cell when including all variables or just the main exposure/control vs event/ no event.

The overall N is 331.

Let's say I have data in a 2x2 table with the typical exposure/control by event/ no event:

```
.                        Event       No Event
.
.     Exposure             103          15
.
.  No Exposure             150          63
```

In this example, the smallest cell size would be 15.  So, I could perform a logistic regression with 1 independent variable, right?

So let's say I wanted to add another variable to the same data, like Race (African American or not, 1 or 0) and here's the cell breakdown:

```
.     Clinic      Event    Race    N
.       0           1        1     121
.       1           1        1     92
.       0           0        1     46
.       0           1        0     29
.       0           0        0     17
.       1           0        1     14
.       1           1        0     11
.       1           0        0      1
```

Would this now mean that my smallest cell is 1?  Or, would I still refer to the original 2x2 table and it would still be 15?

I'm asking because when I run my logistic model in SAS with 6 independent variables on this same data, I do not get any small cell warnings and the convergence criteria is met.  Does this mean I'm okay and don't need to necessarily worry about cell size?

I have been running exact logistic regression models anyway but they take a VERY long time (whole other story).  I'd rather just report the standard LR results to save time (assuming they are legitimate).

Comment: Perhaps this question would be a better fit for [Cross Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/) ?

Comment: oops youre right. i posted on my wrong account. woops

Comment: Cell size refers to combinations, ie a 2x2 table